# C# optional properties in C# 3.0 (2009)

Tags: c#

I am wondering if C# supports optional properties as the following

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public optional string NickName { get; set;}
    ...many more properties...
}
```

so that when I create a Person object I can easily check the validity of input values in a simple loop

```
public bool IsInputOK(Person person)
{
    foreach( var property in person.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if( property.IsOptional())
        {
             continue;
        }
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)property.GetValue(person,null)))
        {
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
 }
```

I have searched on google but didn't get desired solution. Do I really have to hand code validation code for each property manually?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that is a horrible way to perform object validation. It smells...

Comment: I thought this was the best way :( ...I can save about 100 lines of repetitive code by using this approach. Even though I agree that performance will hurt a bit by using reflection.

Comment: Do you care to elaborate on the smell?

Comment: There isn't really technically anything wrong with this, but I think it smells as it's much more common (and simple) to use a nullable type to indicate optionality. If null, the value is considered not present. E.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @WarrenP: Can you elaborate? I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: I think I misunderstand what this original question was actually about.

Comment: Until someone provides a better solution, this is a slick way to validate required parameters.  I like how the [optional] attribute explicitly tells the developer which properties are optional.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can decorate these properties with attribute you define and mark the properties as optional.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property,
                Inherited = false,
                AllowMultiple = false)]
internal sealed class OptionalAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Optional]
    public string NickName { get; set; }
}

public class Verifier
{
    public bool IsInputOK(Person person)
    {
        foreach (var property in person.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.IsDefined(typeof(OptionalAttribute), true))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)property.GetValue(person, null)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

You may also want to take a look at [Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309509.aspx) which has similar capabilities out of the box.

Comment: This is quick, exactly what i am looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

C# does not have an 'optional' keyword, and as @Mitch Wheat says, it's a horrible way to perform validation.

Why can't you just do the validation in the properties setter?

Comment: Because no matter what kind of validation I put in setter. I wouldn't be able to verify the data if setter is not called at all :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to tag the props with attributes and not roll your own validation code, why not try a validation framework?

http://www.codeplex.com/ValidationFramework

Comment: Because a framework for my little task seems to be a bit overkill. I will check it out when I get time. Thanks for the input.