# How to make CC field optional using postal asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, postal

I am using postal to send email using postal service in my asp.net mvc application now the issue is I have to send CC email in specific cases only and I have to make this field optional but I am not been to achieve this so far. Following is my code for this:

View file:

```
@model OAC.Helpers.EmailHelper

To: @Model.To
Form: @Model.From
CC: @Model.CC
Subject: @Model.Subject


Hello,

@Model.Body

@Model.Link

public class EmailHelper : Email
{
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string CC { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public static void SendEmailNotification(string emailAddress, string body, string link, string subject, string from = "OAC Support", string CC = null)
    {
        // Prepare Postal classes to work outside of ASP.NET request
        var viewsPath = Path.GetFullPath(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Views/Emails"));
        var engines = new ViewEngineCollection();
        engines.Add(new FileSystemRazorViewEngine(viewsPath));
        var emailService = new EmailService(engines);
        var email = new EmailHelper
        {
            To = emailAddress,
            CC = CC, 
            Body = body,
            Subject = subject,
            From = from,
            Link = link
        };
        emailService.Send(email);
    }
}
```

Now I want to make the CC field in view optional so that when CC is "null" the view ignores the "@Model.CC" field. Something as following:

```
@model OAC.Helpers.EmailHelper

To: @Model.To
Form: @Model.From
if(Model.CC != null)
{
 CC: @Model.CC
}
Subject: @Model.Subject


Hello,

@Model.Body

@Model.Link
```

Kindly Help! Thank you.

Comment: have a look on [C# optional properties](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1699786/3796048)

Comment: @MohitShrivastava I have tried to do this using "Optional" data annotation but I am unable to find the namespace for it in my project can you kindly guide me that which namespace I need to add for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close, just change the View. Need "@:" before the CC: @Model.Cc

e.g.

```
@if (Model.Cc != null)
{
    @:CC: @Model.Cc
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [Optinal] attributes on your prop.

[Optinal]
public string CC { get; set; }

**proposal**

You can use the model to send the data.

```
public class EMailModel
{

        public string To { get; set; }
        [Optinal]
        public string CC { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }       
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the help but I am unable to find namespace for "Optional" annotation can you please tell me what is the namespace for this?